# Password reset email is not sending

Tags: magento2.3, email, forgot-password

I have tried to reset the password via "forgot password" link in the login page. After I fill in the email address and clicked submit. I have got the below message

> If there is an account associated with this@gmail.com you
>   will receive an email with a link to reset your password.

But I'm not receiving any email related to change the password. Checked Spam folder as well but without success.

Could anyone please help me?

**Magento version: 2.3 Community Version**

Comment: Did you got other mails like order confirmation, create account etc?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any of the emails

Comment: local environment or live?

Comment: It's a testing server

Comment: have you checked your mail log?

Comment: Where to check the mail log?

Comment: other emails are working for orders,customer..?

Answer (score 0):

**For Sending Email You Can Install Module :-**

[Mageplaza SMTP](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-smtp/)

**After Install Module Configure Module :-**

[Configure SMTP](https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/how-to-configure-mailcom-smtp-in-magento-2.html)

Comment: But we have default feature in Magento for sending emails, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by installing **Send mail** package on our development server. Thanks for all your suggestion!